# Strange lines appearing when rendering glass

Tags: rendering

My scene is a cube standing on a checkered plane. For some reason I don't quite understand, when i render the final product lines will appear on the cube, as seen in the picture:
[image: Weird lines along the X and Y axis]

What really bugs me is that I rendered another picture awhile ago, with pretty much the same settings (quite close at least) but this time no lines appeared! Unfortunately the blender file that came with this picture was deleted, making it impossible me to copy from:
[image: Although i might have been using a shade mixer for this one...]

Comment: it would be useful to show the material node setup, the render tab (light path settings); which render engine you are using, or if you can [upload a .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: actually the problem is gone! I simply deleted all textures and made them again from scratch... so I guess we'll never find out what it was..

Comment: actually, i have another blender file with the same problem, it's nearly the same as the one in the picture, only with some different colors and lighting, here's the link for it: [link](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35109)

Comment: it's the cube intersecting the floor rise it up a little and it should be clear; [here is a render](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/85487)

Comment: OMG thank you so much! thx for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The cube was intersecting with the floor which created this effect :

- Select the object and hit G then Shift and move the mouse up slightly
- or you can enable face snapping and move the cube to place it on top of the floor plane

[image]

Here is the render after moving the cube

[image]